# Use of Comma and Colon

Tags: commas, colons

I have been given the following section, and I need to identify the grammatical errors.

> Hawthorne physically set this short story in the town of Milford. It is a common setting for Hawthorne: a New England town set around a church, symbolizing the Puritan values that the villagers strongly upheld.

Is the colon to be replaced a comma?

If yes, why?

Are any other corrections necessary?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Comma Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma) by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of their [Punctuation Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: 'It is a common setting for Hawthorne' is confusing. Is 'it' referential (in which case the preceding sentence/s would be useful)? Does Hawthorne move around?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the reference is pretty clear. "physically set" is the reference for "common setting".

Comment: @Barmar Not if one reads 'Hawthorne' as being a fictional village, which was quite possible before the additional context. '[P]hysically set' is not very clear when it's not there. ELU deals with the mechanics of the language; a required knowledge of story-writing / authors / actual stories makes the question one for Lit.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Language doesn't exist in a vacuum, understanding it generally requires that the language community share some common knowledge. But even without knowing much about Hawthorne, it seems like a stretch trying to interpret that quote as referring to a place rather than a writer, since the place is obviously Milford. Yes, Hawthorne could conceivably be part of Milford, but then the sentence is constructed very strangely (although since the OP is being asked to correct it, that could be intentional).

Comment: The colon would be spot-on if it weren't so old-fashioned. This is a key usage: to introduce a broadening / explanation of what the main clause says. The comma is really not heavy-duty enough. As is usually the case, a dash (usually a spaced en-dash in the UK) can be used to replace the colon.